# Variable is redundant?

Tags: java, android

Why do i get this error of variable being redundant? And i have set the initial value to be 2 but on my mobile device it shows to be 0 when i run the app. Why is this happening?

I am just a new student to the android developing. And i'm doing all the steps by watching a video, still it shows these errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what a _local_ variable is?

Comment: it would be much easier for everybody if you would have posted the code. Really. Nice screenshots btw

Comment: No, i don't actually @SotiriosDelimanolis. I'm pretty basic to programming.

Comment: (My intention was to have you look it up. Help us help you.)

Comment: this is not an error, just a warning, your app will still works

Comment: [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436155/local-variable-is-redundant-java.

Comment: http://funprogramming.org/50-What-are-global-and-local-variables.html

Answer (score 4):

> And i'm doing all the steps by watching a video, still it shows these errors.

No. That's a warning. Not error.

It's redundant because, you declared and never used it. That's a local variable to that method, once the method execution done, no point of accessing it from outside unlike top level members. So declaring a local member without using in the method wont make a lot of sense. That is the reason your IDE complaining.