# javascript eslint local variable is redundant

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to find out how to suppress the eslint error in my javascript code.

> Local variable 'rtn' is redundant

I found the documentation for this here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-return

The docs say:

> If you don't care about disallowing redundant return statements, you can turn off this rule.

But don't say how to disable this error.  The only example they give is having it enabled: `/* eslint no-useless-return: "error" */`.

I'm new to eslint so **how do I do this**?
I've tried

```
/* eslint no-useless-return: "suppress" */
export function dateToYYYYMMDD(theDate : Date, separator  = "-") : string {
  const rtn = theDate.getFullYear() + separator
    + ("0" + (theDate.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + separator
    + ("0" + theDate.getDate()).substr(-2);
  return rtn;
}
```

but this didn't work.  I tried other values like "ok" but that didn't work.
What is the right value to use?

The same question but for Java is here: ["Local variable is redundant" using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436155/local-variable-is-redundant-using-java).  The Java annotation `@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")` does not work in Javascript. :-)

Comment: Are you using an IDE like vscode? If you click the `quick fix` link on the popup that displays the issue it will add the ignore tag for you, but why not just fix the issue instead and make it just; `return theDate.getFullYear() + separator
    + ("0" + (theDate.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + separator
    + ("0" + theDate.getDate()).substr(-2);` or es6 fat arrow `export function dateToYYYYMMDD = (theDate : Date, separator  = "-") : string =>  theDate.getFullYear() + separator
    + ("0" + (theDate.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + separator
    + ("0" + theDate.getDate()).substr(-2);`

Comment: There's no "supress" option in eslint, but you can turn it *off* `/* eslint no-useless-return: "off" */`

Comment: @ChrisW. I set local variable to support debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first thing is, if you want to disable a rule in ESLint, please refer to: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

Second, it doesn't seem like that specific rule warning makes sense in your code - I have tried to reproduce it in here ([ESLint Demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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)) and I get no messages whatsoever after turning `no-useless-return` on.

You might want to double-check your IDE and see if this is really coming from ESLint.

I know that an extension such as SonarLint [would catch such a thing](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1488) so you have to check your editor to see what's triggering the message you got.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it inline like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-return
export function dateToYYYYMMDD(theDate : Date, separator  = "-") : string {
.....
```

this comment must be on top of the line where the error happens.

or you can create an eslint configuration file like `.eslintrc.json` and disable it in the rules, for example:

```
{
   "globals": {
     "__DEV__": "readonly"
   },
   "env": {
     "es2021": true
   },
   "extends": [
     ....
   ],
   "plugins": [
     ....
   ],
   "rules": {
     "no-useless-return": "off"
   }
}
```

or you can return the expression directly instead of storing it in a constant

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to declare a variable and then immediately return it - just return the expression itself without assigning it to a variable first.

```
export function dateToYYYYMMDD(theDate : Date, separator  = "-") : string {
  return theDate.getFullYear() + separator
    + ("0" + (theDate.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + separator
    + ("0" + theDate.getDate()).substr(-2);
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, however, I've used this to support debugging.  Is there another way to see the return value without setting a local variable?  NOTE: I know I could highlight the entire value and enter it into the console, so I'm looking for another solution.